# ASP MVC 5 Logged in User can still access Login and Registration Pages?

Tags: redirect, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, authorization, http-status-code-401

I have an ASP MVC 5 application and I've noticed that logged in user can still access the registration and login pages. I've also noticed that when a logged in user tries to access a controller action to which they are not authorized, they are redirected to the login page. This is confusing because the user is already logged in.

How do I fix this so that unauthorised redirects to some other 401 error page or view.

Answer (score 0):

On registration/login page, you can redirect logged users :

```cs
// GET: /Account/Login
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
{
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Account");
    }
    // ...
}
```

And if you use role, you can override the `AuthorizeAttribute`

```cs
[AuthorizeRole(Roles="Admin")]
public ActionResult Admin()
{
//...
}
```

AuthorizeRoleAttribute.cs
**Edit: Override [HandleUnauthorizedRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.handleunauthorizedrequest.aspx)**

```cs
public class AuthorizeRoleAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
            // Check if user is in roles
            && Roles.Split(',').Any(filterContext.HttpContext.User.IsInRole))
        {
            // Not in any role change view
            filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
            {
                ViewName = "~/Views/Shared/UnauthorizedRole.cshtml"
            };
        }
        else{
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So basically there no way to override the existing Authorize attribute  `[Authorize(Roles = "Manager, Admin")]` so that it functions correctly. What your saying is I have to create my own new Authorize Attribute  and use that instead of the out of the box authorized attribute. `[AuthorizeRole(Roles = "Manager, Admin")]`.

Comment: I think you can use `IOverrideFilter`  and `OverrideAuthentication`. Note that in MVC6 you can use [Policy](https://leastprivilege.com/2015/10/12/the-state-of-security-in-asp-net-5-and-mvc-6-authorization/).