# Custom authorize attribute not working in mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace BugMesh.Authorize
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
    public class CustomAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        BugMesh_Entities db = new BugMesh_Entities();
        private readonly string[] allowedroles;
       public CustomAuthorize(params string[] Roles)
       {  
          this.allowedroles = Roles;  
       }  
       protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)  
       {
           bool authorize = false;  
          foreach (var role in allowedroles)  
          {
              var usr = db.Users.Where(m => m.Role == role);
             if (usr.Count() > 0)
             {  
                authorize = true;  
             }  
          }  
          return authorize;  
       }  
       protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)  
       {  
          filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
       }  
    }
}
```

//authentication applied on UserController Index page
    Controller

```
[CustomAuthorize("Developer")]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Users.ToList());
        }`
```

this line is also written in webconfig file . I want the authentication to be applied that userwith specific role can view the specific View. i also want to know that can i use authentication for login system because i have used Session["UserName"] key but it is not working. Hope i explained my problem.

Comment: The above authentication allow the user of any role to view page.

Comment: Can someone Help????????

Comment: I hope [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38545787/asp-mvc-5-logged-in-user-can-still-access-login-and-registration-pages) answers your question

Comment: @SoftwareNerd The above link is about AuthorizeRoleAttribute that is provided by MS related to User.Identity nut i am having custom Roles of my User table in sql server